# integrating asp.net shopping site with paypal using nvp api

Tags: paypal-nvp

Hai,
I am trying to integrate my shopping site in asp.net with paypal using nvp api method.I dont know from where to start.If anyone have suggestions please reply to this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction in the paypal wizard of https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php